# Using Drill through reports and Analysis Service as Data source in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, mdx

I want to be able to create a report in which you provide a Store Key as a parameter and it will create a table of only that store's sales. For this I have created a parameter called "StoreKey" and a Query which provides the Data Set as:

```
"SELECT NON EMPTY {
   [Measures].[Quantity] -- NOTE there are many more columns in reality
   } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {
            (
                [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]
            )
        } on rows
FROM [cube] 
WHERE WHERE ( STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&["+ @StoreKey + "]",CONSTRAINED))
```

but this provides me the error regarding the `=` sign in the beginning of the Query (I have tested a plethora of different techniques such as `STRTOMEMBER`, `STRTOSET` etc. but none seem to work)

This data set will be used to create a table, where I group on `Weeks` and then on `Dates` in such a way that when you press on a date, a Drill through report is created with more detailed data for that day and store.

I want the subreport to be generated using `StoreKey` and the `Date` used to open up the Drill through report. I want the `StoreKey` parameter to have the same values in the Main report and subreport.

For the latter I configured a `Action` to create a new report in the main report, which should use the `StoreKey` variable along with the `Date` variable to generate the new report.

In my `Subreport` I want to create the first Data set like this:

```
 SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { 
        [Measures].[Quantity] 
        , [Measures].[Total Price]
        , [Measures].[Contribution Margin]
        , [Measures].[Profit Margin] 
    } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { 
        (
            [Dim Time].[Open Hour Bucket].[Open Hour Bucket].ALLMEMBERS
, [Dim Product2].[Product Group].[Product Group].ALLMEMBERS
, [Dim Product2].[Summary].[Summary].ALLMEMBERS 
        ) 
    } ON ROWS
        FROM [DSV_FactStoreSales 1] 
    WHERE ( STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&["+ @StoreKey + "]",CONSTRAINED))
```

But then SSRS tells me that it can't be understood if I use MDX or DAX.

I hope this is not a too broad question, but I've tried to get this to work for so many, many hours so hopefully I can get a push into the right direction. It's so confusing - sometimes forum users says one should use `StrToMember` and sometimes `Parameters!StoreKey.value`.

I make *all* this testing in SSRS in Visual Studios using the *Preview* option. The variable `StoreKey` in the `Main Report` is Shown, the `StoreKey` and `Date` in the `Generated drill through report` is internal. I have tested using different values at `Default values`, `available values` etc. At the moment I have set as `None`.

EDIT:

I finally got a code which actually "works", like this:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Measures].[Quantity]
        ,[Measures].[Total Price]
        ,[Measures].[Contribution Margin]
        ,[Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    { 
        (
            [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30])
            ,STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[" + @StoreKey + "]")
    } on rows
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
```

My issue is however, if I copy this statement into Management studios and replace the variable expression with a hard coded value, like this:

```
STRTOMEMBER('[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]')
```

I get an error that the hierarchies of the dimensions must match, therefor I adjust the code to:

```
    NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]
,STRTOMEMBER('[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]'))} on rows
```

which returns a set. However, using the original *Edited* code in SSRS provides no Error in the **Query designer**, however, when I want to preview the Project I get an error of non matching hiearchies. I then proceed to make the adjustments I did in *Management studios*, (but using a variable instead of a hard coded value), but then I get an empty set in SSRS, which gives various errors as I try to call an empty data set in my table.

Comment: Great effort. Have you tried using the Query Designer in SSRS to write the MDX and create the parameters for you? I usually do that to avoid editing MDX altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your dataset is mapped to a SSRS parameter.

[image]

Also in the `Query Command Text` expression use your MDX expression without `=`, it is not a SSRS expression:

[image]

You have an error in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ( STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&["+@StoreKey+"],CONSTRAINED)",
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date Key].&["+@Date+"],CONSTRAINED" )
```

It should be:

```
WHERE ( STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&["+ @StoreKey + "]",CONSTRAINED), 
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date Key].&[" + @Date + "]",CONSTRAINED ))
```

UPDATE: Try setting the MDX expression from the Query Command Text window.

[image]

This works for me as intended.

[image]

Avoid using SS Management Studio since you can't set SSRS parameters from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very good answer. I've had the parameter set up like that earlier. I also copied your code (and tried some different approaches such as using `'` instead of `"` etc.) but it does not work. I get the error `The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag has been violated` which from what I've googled occurs when one reference the member inappropriately, but I've dragged a specific Store Key out in the designer in order to perfectly mimic the syntax, but I still get the error. I have defined StoreKey as being Text, Allow multiple values, Default value 1046, no available values

Comment: @Cenderze, if your parameter is set to allow multiple values it won't work since a string cannot be concatenated with an array of values. Set the parameter to single value and give it a try just for testing. For multiple value parameters you will have to use STRTOSET and manage to return a string of a set of members from SSRS. How are you populating your parameter?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed my parameter to not allow `multiple values`, but I got the same error regarding CONSTRAINED flag. The parameter is populated from the prompt. Or well, supposedely as I can't get through the data set builder as I can't save the query due to error.

Comment: @Cenderze, are you sure the value typed in the prompt is a member in your dimension? Did you the same for `@Date` parameter?

Comment: I am certain that the value I write in the prompt, 1024, is a valid store key. When I am using the same solution a above, but with `WHERE {STRTOMEMBER('[Dim Date].[Date Key].&[1024]')}` works as intended.

Comment: @Cenderze, In that case set the parameter to single value and use `WHERE {STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date Key].&[" + @StoreKey + "]")}` Be sure your parameter is mapped to a SSRS parameter as shown in my answer.

Comment: I managed to get the query execute (in the query designer), but it wont work when I preview the Project (in SSRS). I have updated my OP, has this happened to you?

Comment: Does not work now either. Can it be some underlying problem, then? Of how the cube itself is set up as? I don't have a hierarchy for `Dim Store2`, but I do have a `Year->Month->Week->Date` hierarchy in `Dim Date` for intsance, do you Think there might be some problem of that nature?

Comment: @Cenderze, Are you sure you parameter value is exactly the same value that you have in the dimension, generally date members don't include time data if your SSRS parameter returns time information it won't work. Also the format should be the same in both dates. Try running a basic script without parameters in Management Studio if it works copy and paste it to SSRS Dataset Query Command Text, if it works the problem would be your parameter or the way you are using it in the MDX script.